# Tag up scoring rules?

Tags: rules, baseball, mlb

Ok, so here is the scenario.

There is one out with runners at first and third bases.

The batter hits a fly ball to shallow right field.  The runner at first base does not tag up and takes off for second base.  The runner at third base waits.  The right fielder makes a diving catch while the runner at third base tags up and crosses home plate before the right fielder throws to first base to get that runner out.

Would the third out be a force out since he did not tag up, thereby eliminating the run scored?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to locate a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_up) that addresses this scenario, though interpreting the ruling from the official rules is somewhat more difficult.  Basically, the scenario you are asking about is considered "doubling a runner off" on a flyout which is considered a "time play" as opposed to a force play -- meaning the run would count. Anything that occurs between the time of the catch and the force out of the improperly tagged up runner is still in play.

> Doubling a runner off is considered a "time play" (as opposed to a force play), which means that even if the doubling-off is the third out of an inning, ***runs which score before the double-off will count*** (unless the run was scored by the same runner that was doubled off, in which case the run will not count in any situation).